# Good way to keep a list of lists sorted on second element when appending new elements?

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7

I have a file with values that I'm looping through. The file consists of two columns with x and y values. I'm adding the x and y values to a list e.g.

```
example_list = []
for line in f:
    example_list.append([line.split()[0], line.split()[1]])
```

However, I want the list to be max 15 lists long, only keeping the highest values from `line.split()[1]`. Two ways to do it is

```
example_list = []
for line in f:
    example_list.append([line.split()[0], line.split()[1]])
top_15 = example_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:15]
```

or

```
example_list = []
count = 0
for line in f:
    if count < 15:
        example_list.append([line.split()[0], line.split()[1]])
        count += 1
    else:
        example_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
        if example_list[0][1] < line.split()[1]:
            example_list[0] = line.split()[1]
```

However, I don't want to read the whole file in memory or call `sort` for every line. What is a better way to keep a list of lists sorted so that a new element only gets added to replace the lowest element in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`heapq` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html); a heap lets you keep the top N items, efficiently, as you go along. There is even a dedicated function for your exact usecase:

```
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

largest_15 = nlargest(15, (line.split()[:2] for line in f), itemgetter(1))
```

This passes in a generator expression, taking care of the loop efficiently.

Under the hood, this method:

- takes the first 15 elements and creates a heap from that.
- calls [`heappushpop()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappushpop) on the heap for all the following items; this adds the item to the heap, then removes the smallest item. As a result the heap only ever contains the 15 largest items.
- when the iterable is done, the heap list is sorted.

Comment: `lambda x: x[0]` would really be so much more readable/comprehensible than `itemgetter(1)`, especially as the latter requires an extra import :)

Comment: @ErikAllik: `itemgetter()` is faster, and also the OP *was already using it*.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Thanks. I think `largest_15 = nlargest(15, (line.split()[:1] for line in f), itemgetter(1))` has to be `largest_15 = nlargest(15, (line.split() for line in f), itemgetter(1))`, otherwise only first column gets picked.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein: Sorry, yes. I meant that to be `[:2]`, since that is what your original code essentially did.